# Jquery Mobile's Table is not Responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using a simple table from jquery mobile site. Here is my page html,

```
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
        <div data-role="content">

            <table data-role="table" id="my-table" data-mode="reflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Movie Title</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>
                            <abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
                        <th>Reviews</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <td><a href="foo.com" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
                        <td>1941</td>
                        <td>100%</td>
                        <td>74</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But my page is look like very ugly. Seems no jquery applied here.
Here is the screen shot,
[image]

Comment: Did you add the required links to your page (scripts, styles etc.)?

Comment: Yes, definately because other controls are working

Comment: can u take a screenshot?

Comment: @Huei, Screen shot is now visible above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Here,
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/where-to-get-jquery-mobile-table-js

> The table functionality is only in the unreleased version 1.3.
>
> If you want to test 1.3, you can check it out from GitHub and build
>   it, or else just download the .js and .css files from the online test
>   docs.
>
> As this isn't even beta software yet, I wouldn't use it in production.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a working responsive table jQM plugin available here: https://github.com/frequent/tableview.

It comes in two modes, non functional one which is only a tableview and functional one which comes in combination with database [plugin](http://www.datatables.net/).

Here's an demo: http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/tableview/demo.html.